# Import CSV with multi-valued (collection) attributes to Cassandra

Tags: csv, collections, cassandra

Suppose I would like to import a csv file into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  comma_delimited_str_list list<ascii>,
  space_delimited_str_list list<ascii>
);
```

where `comma_delimited_str_list` and `space_delimited_str_list` are two list-attributes which use comma and space as their delimiter respectively.

An example csv record would be:

```
12345,"hello,world","stack overflow"
```

where I would like to treat `"hello,world"` and `"stack overflow"` as two multi-valued attributes.

Can I know how to import such CSV file into its corresponding table in Cassandra? Preferably using CQL COPY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CQL 1.2 is able to port CSV file with multi-valued fields directly to a table.  However, the format of those multi-valued fields must match the CQL format.

For example, lists must be in the form `['abc','def','ghi']`, and sets must be in the form `{'123','456','789'}`.

Below is an example of importing CSV formatted data to the `example_table` mentioned in the OP from STDIN:

```
cqlsh:demo> copy example_table from STDIN;
[Use \. on a line by itself to end input]
[copy] 12345,"['hello','world']","['stack','overflow']"
[copy] 56780,"['this','is','a','test','list']","['here','is','another','one']"
[copy] \.

2 rows imported in 11.304 seconds.
cqlsh:demo> select * from example_table;

 id    | comma_delimited_str_list  | space_delimited_str_list
-------+---------------------------+--------------------------
 12345 |            [hello, world] |        [stack, overflow]
 56780 | [this, is, a, test, list] | [here, is, another, one]
```

Importing incorrect formatted list or set values from a CSV file will raise an error:

```
cqlsh:demo> copy example_table from STDIN;
[Use \. on a line by itself to end input]
[copy] 9999,"hello","world"
Bad Request: line 1:108 no viable alternative at input ','
Aborting import at record #0 (line 1). Previously-inserted values still present.
```

The above input should be replaced by `9999,"['hello']","['world']"`:

```
cqlsh:demo> copy example_table from STDIN;
[Use \. on a line by itself to end input]
[copy] 9999,"['hello']","['world']"
[copy] \.

1 rows imported in 16.859 seconds.
cqlsh:demo> select * from example_table;

 id    | comma_delimited_str_list  | space_delimited_str_list
-------+---------------------------+--------------------------
  9999 |                   [hello] |                  [world]
 12345 |            [hello, world] |        [stack, overflow]
 56780 | [this, is, a, test, list] | [here, is, another, one]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me in CQL 3.1.1:  `copy mylist from STDIN;` 
`'test', "['foo','bar','baz']"`  `Record #0 (line 1) has the wrong number of fields (4 instead of 2)`.

Comment: This is what I had to do: `copy mylist from STDIN;` 
`'test', [\'foo\'\,\'bar\'\,\'baz\']` 
`\.`