# use cql copy for map data

Tags: csv, cassandra, cql

there is one post for copying multi-value data like list and set from csv to cassandra table,

[Import CSV with multi-valued (collection) attributes to Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140645/import-csv-with-multi-valued-collection-attributes-to-cassandra)

has any one done this for map type data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, I'll give you a simple example that uses both a `map` and a `list`.  Consider the following table designed to hold starship data, as well as a list of crew and passengers:

```
CREATE TABLE shipregistry (
  name text,
  class text,
  hullnumber text,
  crew map<text,text>,
  passengers list<text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name))
);
```

I will load this table's data from the following text file (`/home/aploetz/shipregistry_20150302.csv`), which has a header and a single row of pipe-delimited data:

```
name|class|crew|hullnumber|passengers
Serenity|03-K64-Firefly|{'1st Officer': 'Zoey Washburne', 'captain': 'Malcolm Reynolds', 'engineer': 'Kaylee Frye', 'pilot': 'Hoban Washburne'}|G-82659|['Simon Tam', 'River Tam', 'Derial Book', 'Inara Serra']
```

I will then import it using the cqlsh `COPY` command:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:presentation> COPY shipregistry FROM
'/home/aploetz/shipregistry_20150302.csv' WITH HEADER=true and DELIMITER='|';

1 rows imported in 0.017 seconds.
```

Important to note, is that the `list` data for the `passengers` column, is comma-delimited and enclosed in brackets:

```
['Simon Tam', 'River Tam', 'Derial Book', 'Inara Serra']
```

Likewise, the `map` data for the `crew` column, is a comma-delimited list of key-value pairs and enclosed in braces:

```
{'1st Officer': 'Zoey Washburne', 'captain': 'Malcolm Reynolds', 'engineer': 'Kaylee Frye', 'pilot': 'Hoban Washburne'}
```

I chose a pipe as a delimiter to make this easier on myself and avoid potential clashes with commas in the collection types.

Comment: wonderful. I will try it out. was this searchable in the doc?

Comment: @user1058511 No, I only know this because I had to do it last week.  Unfortunately some of the docs need to be flushed out with some more detailed examples.

Comment: @Aaron -- What if the mapped field is missing data? IE: Came out of the export `{'factor': '1', 'rep': }` - where `rep` was missing the value? CQL pukes back a nice `No viable alternative at input...`

Comment: @tymeJV I'd be curious to know what the data in the map looks like in cqlsh.  But you're right, COPY should probably export a set of empty quotes (in the case of a TEXT) or something else that will work with a direct import.

Comment: @Aaron -- Yeah that's what I was thinking. Ended up dropping the column and re-exporting - the solve-all solution!